# R: symbol in list element is different when whole list is printed, compared to when only element is printed

Tags: r, regex, special-characters

Ok, this is at risk of being downvoted real hard, because it is impossible for me to reproduce any code in here, but here goes:

I have a list of dataframes. When I get one column of one of the dataframes, I get for the last rows:

```
mylist[[7]][2]
```

[image]

You see the equal sign? If I only want to see the 135th element, I get:

```
mylist[[7]][135,2]
```

[image]

Also, I cannot match the "*≤*" symbol with gsub. It just does not find it:

```
> gsub("≤","test",mylist[[7]][135,2])
[1] "151≤"
>

> gsub("=","test",mylist[[7]][135,2])
[1] "151≤"
```

**EDIT**:

```
> x <- mylist[[7]][135,2]
> dput(x)
"151="
>
```

**EDIT2**:

```
> Encoding(rs[[7]][135,2])
[1] "UTF-8"



 Encoding(unlist(rs[[7]][2],use.names=F)
...
    [121] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"
    [129] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "UTF-8"
```

**EDIT 3**:

```
> library(stringi)
> stri_escape_unicode(mylist[[7]][135,2])
[1] "151\\u2264"
>
```

Comment: You can possibly reproduce it by doing `x <- mylist[[7]][135,2]` then post the output of `dput(x)`

Comment: My best guess is that is must be some sort of text encoding problem? Have you tried using `base::Encoding()` on both the vector and the single element?

Comment: @RichScriven: that gives me: > x <- mylist[[7]][135,2]
> dput(x)
"151="

Comment: @divibisan: No, I have not tried that, I've never heard of that :)

Comment: @divibisan: they both seem to be UTF-8, if you look at my EDIT2 above:)

Comment: That's weird that `dput` shows it correctly, it's only the implicit print function that shows it incorrectly

Comment: @divibisan: Yes, indeed! At look at both gsub functions. It does not get a match with "=" either...

Comment: What is the OS? [There is no issue in Linux](http://rextester.com/OYJ40757). Same in Windows. I cannot test on Mac.

Comment: Windows 7 is the OS

Comment: You need to identify the exact char codes of the string, then it will be possible to say something.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thank you for helping me out! Could you explain to me how I find the exact char codes? I cannot find anything when I google this.

Comment: `library(stringi)` then `stri_escape_unicode(mylist[[7]][135,2])`

Comment: thank you for that! I posted results in "edit 3" above!